# Will storing Activity Context in a DialogFragment cause a memory leak?

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-leaks, android-context

I'm doing the following all throughout my project, would this produce a memory leak?

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mContext = activity;
}
```

and then later in a method like this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                .setTitle(getActivity().getString(
                        R.string.common_error))
                .setMessage(getActivity().getString(
                        R.string.common_please_try_again))
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, null)
                .show();
```

Is doing the above ok? What if I'm trying to show the AlertDialog in onPostExecute() of an AsyncTask?

EDIT: as was pointed out, this would produce a memory leak since I'm trying to access the Activity's Context beyond its lifetime.

But would the below cause the same issue? What is a good general solution for showing an AlertDialog from a DialogFragment?

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallback = (MyCallback)activity;
}
```

and then later in a method like this:

```
if(mCallback != null){
   mCallback.showAlertDialog();
}
```

Would this produce a memory leak, would wrapping it in a WeakReference fix any memory leaks?

Comment: `Fragment` has `getActivity()`, which you can call when you need the activity that is hosting it.

Comment: I was doing that before but calling getActivity() checking if null and if not null calling getActivity() again to get the Context. I got an NPE from doing this I think because the Activity got gc'ed *right* after my first call to getActivity(). Would storing the activity after the first call to getActivity() and then using it cause any potential memory leaks?

Comment: You should not be gaining anything by doing this. And, if you *are*, that's because you have introduced a memory leak. Your fragment should not be doing anything with an activity in a background thread or after `onDetach()`. In between `onAttach()` and `onDetach()`, `getActivity()` should return a non-`null` value. IMHO, you are at best patching over the real problem: trying to use an activity when your fragment should not be working with one.

Comment: Hm that makes sense. I should probably change this to instead use an interface to tell the Activity itself to show this AlertDialog instead of the Fragment doing it. Thanks for the help! And thanks for every other post I've read from you :)

Comment: Actually I think doing the above would also cause a memory leak. I'll update my question with an example.

Comment: Casting to an interface is merely a compilation thing. It does not impact the issue of leaks. If you are getting an NPE from `getActivity().showAlertDialog()`, then you have a different issue: trying to have a fragment -- one that is detached from anything -- trigger showing a dialog. The solution is not "try to hack not losing the activity reference". The solution is figuring out why you have this code being called after the fragment has been detached, then revamping your approach to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Before showing the `AlertDialog` you can check if the `Fragment` is added to an `Activity`

```
if (getActivity != null) { 
  // Show dialog
}
```

or

```
if (isAdded()) { 
  // Show dialog
}
```